# Deploy Nodejs backend to AWS Amplify backebnd

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, react-fullstack

I have a React Front End and Nodejs Backend. I pushed it to GitHub. I want AWS Aplify to deploy it from GitHub.

AWS Amplify deploys the react front end without issues. However, I cannot find a solution on how to make it deploy the backend as well. All I find is that you have to create aws cli and deploy it separately or something. Is it possible for it to take the backend from GitHub and deploy it the same way as it deploys the Front end?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use amplify add api and then import your current BE in the functions that are created and linked to the api. After that the whole deploy will be automated. This link should help: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/restapi/restapi/